# Max Value of (Stops) with criteria of (Driver Full Name, StopCompletedDate, Route) in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, measure

I am struggling to get a max value of Stops based on unique criteria for other columns (Driver Full Name, StopCompletedDate, Route) and summing the max values that will give us total number of stops per DC.

Data looks like below:

| Route | Stop | DC | StopCompletedDate | Driver Full Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 551 | 1 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 1 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 1 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 1 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 2 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 2 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 3 | 012 | 8/6/2022 | Michael Robinson |
| 551 | 2 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 551 | 1 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Marc Armamento |
| 520 | 3 | 012 | 8/5/2022 | Anthony Gonzalez |
| 550 | 2 | 001 | 8/5/2022 | Billy White |

Looking for results like this:

| DC | Sum of Stops |
| --- | --- |
| 012 | 8 |
| 001 | 2 |

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried. I suggest you examine the `SUMMARIZE` and/or `GROUPBY' Dax functions.  Or you can do this in the Query Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`select dc,sum(maximum) from  (select dc,max(Stop) maximum from table group by Driver_Full_Name,Stop,CompletedDate,Route) table_sub;`